# My scrollable ui stack view has spaces in it and I have no idea why

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistoryboard, uistackview

My scrollable ui stack view has spaces in it and I have no idea why... Any help is appreciated!

Main story board

[[image: Main.storyboard]

Stack view constraints

[image: constraints]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the Spacing Attribute (Attribute Inspector)?

[image]

Comment: It was already set to zero, unfortunately that is not the problem